# Is there any Lefschetz-like principle for representations of finite groups?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Representation theory (at least the origin of this terminology) aims to exhibit a model (a represetative) in the group of matrices for an abstract  group which is known by only its group law. So complex representations is a satisfying beautiful theory with Schur's theorem, Frobenius reciprocity, Artin, Brauer theorems and various results about irreducible degrees for finite groups.

But my concern is that the field of complex numbers is extraneous to groups. Do we have theorems like $\sum_j d_j^2 = |G|$ when $d_j$ runs though all irreducible degrees of $G$ over an unspecified algebraically closed field. Because the complex case uses character theory with Hermitian structure on the vector space of complex-valued class functions I am not sure if this result is available for a general field.

I have not studied what is known as modular representation theory. Are all non-modular cases no different from the theory over complex numbers? (always working over algebraically closed field). Do the degrees of irreducible 
representations divide the order of the group whatever the base field is?

Instead of asking for questions individually of this nature let me ask:

*Is there an analogue of Lefschetz principle of Algebraic Geometry  that is valid for finite group representations?* so that to study non-modular representations it suffices to study complex representations.

Comment: Certainly any algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 will reproduce the classical results (in fact, a much smaller extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ suffices).    But in prime characteristic $p$ dividing $|G|$ everything tends to change.   It's true however that when $p$ doesn't divide $|G|$, you get back the same picture as in characteristic 0.  All of this can be found in standard sources.

Comment: I am uncomfortable about using the property of complex conjugation. This seems to play a crucial role in the proof of Schur orthogonality relations.

Comment: Character theory provides a very elegant tool when studying representations of finite groups but many statements can be proved without using characters. For instance, the identity you mention follows from the fact that the group algebra $\mathbb{K}G$ is semisimple when $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraically closed field whose characteristic doesn't divide $|G|$. In particular $\mathbb{K}G$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of matrix algebras $M_{d_i}(\mathbb{K})$. Counting dimensions as $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces gives you the numerical identity. This can be proved without character theory.

Comment: See for instance (27.21) on pg. 186 of Curtis and Reiner's fantastic book "Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras".

Comment: @Jay Taylor: Thanks for the reference. Somehow the massive size  of Curtis and Reiner made me stay away from  it. I'll now definitely look up there.  You have now given a clear answer. Yes, Wedderburn's structure theorem gives a way avoiding complex characters. You can make this comment an answer.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to abandon characters altogether (but they might not always give much information).   AMS has reprinted the classic text by I.M. Issacs, where you should look at Chapter 9: http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=CHEL-359-H

Comment: Yes, I have seen that wonderful book. Remember reading from there that an irreducible complex character of degree > 1 vanishes somewhere. And the proof uses AM>GM inequality!

Comment: There's no need to mention complex conjugation in the theory. The conjugate of a character $\chi(g)$, over any field, is $\chi(g^{-1})$.

Comment: Although degrees of irreducible representations of finite groups over algebraically closed fields of prime characteristic p need not divide the group order, it is worth mentioning that this divisibility property does hold for solvable groups, and more generally, for p-solvable groups. Since a group with order not divisible by p is automatically p-solvable, this generalizes the fact that the divisibility property holds if p does not divide the group order.

Comment: Nice to get a comment from the master himself! Thanks for your explicit statement about divisibility that I did not know earlier. (Perhaps I did not study the textbooks  carefully). As the divisibility proofs used the fact *an algebraic integer that is rational is a usual integer* I could not guess about representations in prime characteristic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was encouraged to make my comment an answer, so will do so.

If $G$ is a finite group and $\mathbb{K}$ is a field then many interesting results that can be proved using character theory can also be proved by analysing the structure of the group algebra $\mathbb{K}G$. For instance by (27.20) of Curtis and Reiner's "Representation theory of finite groups and associative algebras" we have

$$\mathbb{K}G \cong \bigoplus_i M_{d_i}(\mathbb{K})$$

is a direct sum of matrix algebras whenever $\mathbb{K}$ is an algebraically closed field whose characteristic does not divide the order of the group. Counting dimensions this gives the desired numerical identity

$$|G| = \sum_i d_i^2.$$

Note however that dropping either of these conditions can be problematic. It is well known that if the characteristic of $\mathbb{K}$ divides the order of the group then $\mathbb{K}G$ is no longer semisimple. However, if the field is too small then the irreducible representations of $G$ may not be realisable over that field. For instance, take $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{Q}$ and $G$ to be a cyclic group.

Comment: To supplement this: note by the way that when $p$ is odd, Eisenstein's criterion tells us that the cyclic group of order $p$ has an irreducible representation of degree $p-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, so the degree of an irreducible characteristic $0$ representation need not divide the group order in general. Also, the degrees of irreducible characteristic $p$ representations (even over algebraically closed fields) need not divide the group order.

Comment: That's a nice example for $C_p$, I'd never thought about that before.

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: Thanks for your valuable comment connecting Eisenstein criterion. Learnt something new. I am curious about irreducible degrees not dividing the order of the group. Surprised that such a fact is not mentioned in textbooks. Can you direct me to a reference for an example of that?

Comment: I have given a characteristic 0 example. In characteristic 3, the simple group PSU(3,3) has an absolutely irreducible representation of degree 15, but has order 6048. There are many more examples in the "Atlas of Brauer Characters".